# "Подружить" счётчики

Tags: javascript, counter

Доброго времени суток господа, как сделать так чтобы один счётчик зависел от другого? Ну или чтобы слайдер работал корректно. 
Сейчас работает только один раз.

```js
(function sliderMove(){

let slide = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");

function nextSlider(){
    
    let i = 1;

    return function(){
        if(i < slide.length){
            return slide[i++].classList.add("active");
        }
    }
}
let counterNext = nextSlider();
let next = document.querySelector("#slider-next");
next.addEventListener("click", counterNext);

function prevSlider(){
    
    let i = slide.length - 1;

    return function(){
        if(i > 0){
            return slide[i--].classList.remove("active");
        }
    }
}
let counterPrev = prevSlider();
let prev = document.querySelector("#slider-prev");
prev.addEventListener("click", counterPrev);
}());
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main-slide{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .slide{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transition: .5s all;
  }
  .not-active{
    transform: translate3d(0px, 100vh, 0px);
  }
  .active{
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
  #slide1{
    perspective: 1px;
    background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/bd/d0/b4bdd071a02bbff4803b67d86aa7984c.jpg);
  }
  #slide2{
    perspective: 2px;
    background-image: url(https://xubuntu.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/8fbb/40103442821_db033c72a4_o-web.jpg);
  }
  #slide3{
    perspective: 3px;
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1511447333015-45b65e60f6d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjExMjU4fQ&w=1000&q=80);
  }
  #slider-prev, #slider-next{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  #slider-prev{
    left: 0px;
  }
  #slider-next{
    right: 0px;
  }
  .perspective{
    
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

```html
    <div id="slider-prev">prev</div>
    <div id="slider-next">next</div>

    <div class="main-slide">
        <div class="slide active" id="slide1">
        </div>
        <div class="slide not-active" id="slide2">
        </div>
        <div class="slide not-active" id="slide3">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Тэкс, вынес переменную i на уровень выше. Вроде начал работать, но через раз и с ошибками)

Comment: Примерно понял суть проблемы, querySelectorAll передаёт массив начиная с 1. Мой реверсивный счётчик считает с 0.

Answer (score 0):

Всё, разобрался!
Сделал общий i и сделал инкремент префиксным. Всем спасибо) можно закрывать всё работает как надо.

```js
(function sliderMove(){

let slide = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
let i = 0;
function nextSlider(){
    
    

    return function(){
        
        if(i < slide.length - 1){
            console.log(i);
            return slide[++i].classList.add("active");
        }
    }
}
let counterNext = nextSlider();
let next = document.querySelector("#slider-next");
next.addEventListener("click", counterNext);

function prevSlider(){
    
    

    return function(){
        
        if(i > 0){
            console.log(i);
            return slide[i--].classList.remove("active");
        }
    }
}
let counterPrev = prevSlider();
let prev = document.querySelector("#slider-prev");
prev.addEventListener("click", counterPrev);
}());
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main-slide{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .slide{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transition: .5s all;
  }
  .not-active{
    transform: translate3d(0px, 100vh, 0px);
  }
  .active{
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
  #slide1{
    perspective: 1px;
    background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/bd/d0/b4bdd071a02bbff4803b67d86aa7984c.jpg);
  }
  #slide2{
    perspective: 2px;
    background-image: url(https://xubuntu.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/8fbb/40103442821_db033c72a4_o-web.jpg);
  }
  #slide3{
    perspective: 3px;
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1511447333015-45b65e60f6d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjExMjU4fQ&w=1000&q=80);
  }
  #slider-prev, #slider-next{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  #slider-prev{
    left: 0px;
  }
  #slider-next{
    right: 0px;
  }
  .perspective{
    
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

```html
    <div id="slider-prev">prev</div>
    <div id="slider-next">next</div>

    <div class="main-slide">
        <div class="slide active" id="slide1">
        </div>
        <div class="slide not-active" id="slide2">
        </div>
        <div class="slide not-active" id="slide3">
        </div>
    </div>
```